# WPF ComboBox Binding works if previous record had no matching item in the ItemsSource collection and fails if it did

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, null

I have the following WPF Combobox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="performanceItemsource" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedReport.Performances}"  >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
 ...
    <ComboBox Name="cbxPlanPerf" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      SelectedValuePath="MSDPortfolioID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PlanPerfID}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource performanceItemsource}}"/>
```

The Source for the `CollectionViewSource` is:

```
public List<MSDExportProxy> Performances
{
  get
  {
    if (Portfolio != null)
    {
      return (from a in Portfolio.Accounts where a.MSDPortfolioID != null select new MSDExportProxy(a))
        .Concat<MSDExportProxy>(from g in Portfolio.Groups where g.MSDPortfolioID != null select new MSDExportProxy(g))
        .Concat<MSDExportProxy>(from p in new[] { Portfolio } where p.MSDPortfolioID != null select new MSDExportProxy(p))
        .ToList<MSDExportProxy>();
    }
    return new List<MSDExportProxy>();
  }
}
```

The bound property `PlanPerfID` is a string.

I move between records using a ListBox control.  The ComboBox works fine if the previous record had no items in its ComboBox.ItemsSource. If there were any items in the previous record's ComboBox.ItemsSource then the new record won't find its matching item in the `ItemsSource` collection.  I've tried setting the `ItemsSource` in both XAML and the code-behind, but nothing changes this odd behavior.  How can I get this darn thing to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick and dirty solution to my problem.  I just happen to have a public `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method on my Report entity and I discovered that if I called `SelectedReport.NotifyPropertyChanged("PlanPerfID")` in the Report ListBox's `SelectionChanged` event that it was enough of a jolt to get the `ComboBox` to re-evaluate and find its matching item in the `ItemsSource`.  Yeah, it's KLUGE...

UPDATE: I also wound up needing to add `SelectedReport.NotifyPropertyChanged("Performances")` for some situations...

UPDATE 2: Okay, turns out the above wasn't bullet proof and I ran across a situation that broke it so I had to come up with a better workaround:

1. Altered the `SelectedReport` property in the Window's code-behind, adding a private flag (`_settingCombos`) to keep the Binding from screwing up the bound values until the dust has settled from changin the `ItemSource`:

   ```
   private bool _settingCombos = false;
   private Report _SelectedReport;
   public Report SelectedReport
   {
     get { return _SelectedReport; }
     set 
     {
       _settingCombos = true;
       _SelectedReport = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedReport");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Created a proxy to bind to in the Window code-behind that will refuse to update the property's value if the `_settingCombos` flag is `true`:

   ```
   public string PlanPerfID_Proxy
   {
     get { return SelectedReport.PlanPerfID; }
     set
     {
       if (!_settingCombos)
       {
         SelectedReport.PlanPerfID = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("PlanPerfID_Proxy");
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Added an extra Notification in the Report ListBox's `SelectionChanged` event along with code to reset the `_settingCombos` flag back to `false`:

   ```
   private void lbxReports_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     //KLUGE: Couldn't get the ComboBoxes associated with these properties to work right
     //this forces them to re-evaluate after the Report has loaded
     if (SelectedReport != null)
     {
       NotifyPropertyChanged("PlanPerfID_Proxy");
       _settingCombos = false;
     }
   }
   ```
4. Bound the `ComboBox` to the `PlanPerfID_Proxy` property (instead of directly to the `SelectedReport.PlanPerfID` property.

Wow, what a hassle!  I think that this is simply a case of .NET's binding logic getting confused by the dynamic nature of the `ComboBox.ItemSource`, but this seems to have fixed it.  Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ICollectionViews` in combination with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property when handling lists / ObservableCollection in Xaml. The ICollectionView in the viewmodel can handle all the things needed, e.g. sorting, filtering, keeping track of selections and states.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentReport.Performances}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private readonly IReportService _reportService;
        private ObservableCollection<ReportViewModel> _reports = new ObservableCollection<ReportViewModel>();
        private PerformanceViewModel _currentPerformance;
        private ReportViewModel _currentReport;

        public ObservableCollection<ReportViewModel> Reports
        {
            get { return _reports; }
            set { _reports = value; OnPropertyChanged("Reports");}
        }

        public ReportViewModel CurrentReport
        {
            get { return _currentReport; }
            set { _currentReport = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentReport");}
        }

        public PerformanceViewModel CurrentPerformance
        {
            get { return _currentPerformance; }
            set { _currentPerformance = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPerformance");}
        }

        public ICollectionView ReportsView { get; private set; }
        public ICollectionView PerformancesView { get; private set; }        

        public ViewModel(IReportService reportService)
        {
            if (reportService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reportService");
            _reportService = reportService;

            var reports = _reportService.GetData();
            Reports = new ObservableCollection<ReportViewModel>(reports);

            ReportsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Reports);
            ReportsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            ReportsView.CurrentChanged += OnReportsChanged;
            ReportsView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }

        private void OnReportsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedReport = ReportsView.CurrentItem as ReportViewModel;
            if (selectedReport == null) return;

            CurrentReport = selectedReport;

            if(PerformancesView != null)
            {
                PerformancesView.CurrentChanged -= OnPerformancesChanged;
            }

            PerformancesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CurrentReport.Performances);
            PerformancesView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            PerformancesView.CurrentChanged += OnPerformancesChanged;
            PerformancesView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }

        private void OnPerformancesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedperformance = PerformancesView.CurrentItem as PerformanceViewModel;
            if (selectedperformance == null) return;

            CurrentPerformance = selectedperformance;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that is a lot big paradigm shift from the way I am currently doing things.  Looks like you would have me put this ViewModel code in the form's code-behind?